# Java Security Class Couldn't be found

Tags: security, java, encryption

When launching my program the next error pops out

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.crypto.SunJCE_b

which means this class is missing although I've found this class manually, works via jar/ide but doesn't works prefectly via service.

Maybe I need to make a few modifications? but which?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: In my case (Tomcat 6 + Java 1.6 on Ubuntu 14.04) my problem was  solved by adding the JCE unlimited strength crypto jars (as @Thedaego answered) and then restarting Tomcat.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if this is relevant to *your* problem but I was experiencing the exact same behavior due to versions of the JCE Policy files I was using.

Using the proper [Unlimited Strength Cryptography Extenstions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-6-download-429243.html) solved this issue for me. I believe I might have accidentally installed the extensions for Java 7 as opposed to 6. (I was using Java 6 for compilation)

For a windows machine, they should be installed in the jre/lib/security folder of your installed JDK, for example: c:\program files\Java\jdk1.6.0_33\jre\lib\security

Answer (score 4):

The class should be located in the `jce.jar` file. This has to be on the classpath. Double check your classpath parameters which should be either the `-cp` parameter if you start the application *without* the `-jar` option xor the `Class-Path` entry in the jars manifest if you use `java -jar myapp.jar` to start you program

---

You found a common WTF ;) - that's a widely unknown rule: **if** you start you app with the `-jar` option, **then** the `-cp` option and the `CLASSPATH` environment are ignored. **Then** the classpath must specified inside the Manifest only.

*Quick workaround* - assuming, you "main class" is named `com.example.App`, then start the application like this:

```
java -cp jce.jar com.example.App
```

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question how can I check my classpath? it seems by just running java -jar -cp jce.jar myapp.jar doesnt work for me +)

Answer (score 1):

We had the permissions of our files only set to be read only by root and gave us a similar error.
Change permissions and things worked!

> $ pwd
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java/jre/lib/security
>   $ ls -l
>   total 128
>   -rw-r--r--.  1 root root  2177 Mar  1  2013 blacklist
>   -rw-r--r--.  1 root root 84029 Sep 30 18:01 cacerts
>   -rw-r--r--.  1 root root  2253 Mar  1  2013 java.policy
>   -rw-r--r--.  1 root root 11804 Mar  1  2013 java.security
>   -rw-r--r--.  1 root root   109 Mar  1  2013 javaws.policy
>   -rw-r--r--.  1 root root  2481 Sep 16 16:50 local_policy.jar
>   -rw-r--r--.  1 root root     0 Mar  1  2013 trusted.libraries
>   -rw-r--r--.  1 root root  1924 Jul 18 17:42 truststore-epicinterbld.pem
>   -rw-r--r--.  1 root root  2465 Sep 16 16:50 US_export_policy.jar

Answer (score 0):

Check which jre is being used when you're launching and make sure the jre/lib/ext folder contains sunjce_provider.jar

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you aren't using the extensions directory option.  In the past when I used the extensions directory option instead of a classpath it was no longer able to load the Security libraries and policies.  When I went back to using an explicit classpath the Security functionality resumed working.

Comment: Well if you mean when exporting then no, I'm just extracting/packing required jars into the runnable jar..

Answer (score 0):

I deleted various older JDKs in /Library/Java/VirtualMachine (got osx) and after restarting android studio the error was gone, but I hat to set the jdk again. Maybe it helps others.

Answer (score 0):

This is issue with the JRE version, it should point to the same jre version as being used by the program, it looks for "jre/lib/security" should be under the same jdk of your program