# Could not initialize class javax.crypto.SunJCE_b

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

I have a Java servlet application developed and on my develpment PC everything works as expected including using SFTP programmatically to copy over a PDF using HTTPS on port 8443 etc and with SSL certificates in place too.

However, when I attempt to run the application on the Live server I receive the error;

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.crypto.SunJCE_b

On investigation, some are suggesting check the jce.jar.  But I have ensured the jce.jar is present and also created a "lib" folder in my project and copied the jar there and placed the jar on my build path but still the problem exists.

How do I resolve this please?  Thanks in advance.  Here is the console output from right after Tomcat has started the application;

#

```
08-Jan-2014 10:45:44 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 12715 ms
08-Jan-2014 10:47:42 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor run
SEVERE: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.crypto.SunJCE_b
at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(DashoA13*..)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.JsseJce.getCipher(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.RSAClientKeyExchange.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.tasks(SecureNioChannel.java:285)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.handshakeUnwrap   
(SecureNioChannel.java:343)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.handshake
(SecureNioChannel.java:193)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run
(NioEndpoint.java:1642)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: on which application server your application is deployed?

Comment: couple of suggestions here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885639/java-security-class-couldnt-be-found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `jce.jar` must be inside the folder `WEB-INF/lib` of the deployed web application.

Comment: Thanks Toni.  I placed the jce.jar in the projects WEB-INF/lib folder and redeployed the project but it still didn't work.  Same error.  Do I also have to add jce.jar specifically to the project Build Path

Comment: Do you run the same JDK on your development PC and live system?

Comment: I was checking for any differences in the environmnet and found that the JRE's are exactly the same version except for one is 64 bit. The development machine's java -version states;java version "1.6.0_29"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_29-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.4-b02, mixed mode, sharing)
While the Live server java -version states; java version "1.6.0_29"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_29-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.4-b02, mixed mode)
Could this be making the difference?

Comment: We don't have the JDK on the Live server only the JRE.  The differnce is mentioned above.  Thanks for your assistance so far Toni

Comment: I don't think so. I was thinking that perhaps in the live system there was an old version of the JDK where the class was not implemented yet.

Comment: I don't think this will be relevant Toni but can I confirm with you - the development PC everyting is 32 bit, Java SDK, Tomcat, Eclipse etc but on the Live server Java and Tomcat are 64 bit.  Would this make a difference?  Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this problem pop up very often and there seems to be a lot of confusion around it. The actual reason this is happening is because the JRE you are using to run your application has been set up with the unrestricted JCE policy jars inside its jre/lib folder (inside your jdk install folder).

If your current project does not need these, then you can move then out of this folder temporarily. This will remove the requirement on the jce libraries and you will no longer see this error.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  This currently is not an issue.  We have it resolved for the time being.  But I value your input as I am still slowly having to get to grips with Java and Tomcat etc.  What I really need is a decent Java project I can do from start to finish and not maintaining someone elses.  Thanks